# Textbox dot not accept symbols and capital letters without button click in html/php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I have a textbox and I want without button click the textbox do not accept symbols and capital letter. It accept alphanumeric value only. But I do not want to check on button click like:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $username) {
  echo "Looks good\n";
} else {
echo "Invalid character\n";
}

if (preg_match('/^\p{Xan}+$/', $username) {
echo "Looks good\n";
 } else {
echo "Invalid character\n";
}
```

I want textbox do not accept symbol and capital letter, when user started typing nothing happen.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028527/html5-regex-pattern-for-textbox-validation-allow-alphabet-spaces-and-hyphens

Comment: Not working what I want still accepting symbols. I do not want to validate it on button click through php.

Comment: @protoproto Not working what I want still accepting symbols. I do not want to validate it on button click through php.

Answer (score 2):

Accept only alphanumeric string in textbox using jquery

```
$('#texboxID').on('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   alert("Accept only small letter and numbers");
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\b` in the character class? In this context, it means "not a backspace".

Comment: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b.

Comment: Not in character class. It's a nonsense to put a word boundary in a character class! *a fortiori* in a negated character class.

Comment: If you want to apply 'Whole Word', you can do: '^\b[a-z0-9]+\b$' Here the Word boundary is outside the character class.